# C# Pattern match arrays

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, switch-expression

```cs
var x = new int[] { 1, 2 };
var y = x switch {
  { 1, 2 } => "yea",
  _ => "nay"
};
```

fails to compile.

How can I pattern-match arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expand the elements of the array yourself like so

```
var x = new int[] { 1, 2 };
var y = (x[0], x[1]) switch {
  (1, 2) => "yea",
  _ => "nay"
};
```

Comment: And if one can choose to change the type of `x`, the code could be simplified by letting `(int, int) x = (1, 2);` ==> `var y = x switch { (1, 2) => "yea", _ => "nay" };`.